# CircleCi *configure the build* couldn't find commit

Tags: testing, continuous-integration, circleci

If somebody uses CircleCi for test integration
(https://circleci.com/),
today we found next problem (after some months of using):

```
$ configure the build (0s)
 Could not find commit our_last_commit_number in the repo
```

All settings for the git presented in the Circle.
Anyone saw this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a temporary problem with CircleCI, it should be fixed shortly! See https://twitter.com/circleci/status/319473067481001985